# StorageConnectionString does not work when it is located in App.config

Tags: .net, console-application, azure-storage

I have .NET Console Application project and I am trying connect to Azure Storage.

I paste this code to App.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <appSettings>
      <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<accountName>;AccountKey=<accessKey>" />
    </appSettings>

    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

and in program.cs i am using this code

```
// Retrieve storage account from app setting (App.config)
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionStr‌​ing"]);
```

but following error is thrown

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll
```

when i paste StorageConnectionString directly it works!

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=h.....")
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: You need yo paste the config into `App.config` not in `App.setting`.

Comment: thank you but it was my typo, i have it in App.config already. I edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a reference to System.Configuration in your project and a namespace declaration for the same. By default, some project templates, like Console Application, do not reference this assembly so you must manually reference it.
Also, check that your project uses latest Azure SDK. Right-Click on your Azure project and select Properties. Under the Application tab, you should see a button to Update your Azure SDK.